# Unable to boot to Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu on a separate drive

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have searched everywhere on the internet and I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. I have an Alienware Aurora and with it came Windows 7. Recently, I inserted an additional HDD and installed Ubuntu on it. Upon boot up, I do not have the option of booting to a specific OS. I checked and everything is still on the original drive. I even went into my BIOS and tried to switch the drive from which the computer booted, but there was no option for the original drive. I also tried using boot-repair to no avail. Thanks in advance for the help. I realize that similar questions have been asked on these forums but none of them seem to be any help to me.
Edit:
I meant to add that I tried removing the Ubuntu drive therefore forcing it to boot to Windows. When I did this, it started a GRUB command line which I am completely unfamiliar with.

Comment: Take a look at [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

Comment: please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add entry in Grub to boot windows.

So just edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` (using SUDO) and add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
menuentry ‘Windows 7′ {
set root=’(hd0,msdos2)’
chainloader +1
}
```

`(hd0,msdos2)` Refers to first HDD ( /dev/sda2 ).

After making changes into grub, you need to update grub.cfg by using below command.

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Now when you boot your system, you will get Option to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

Answer (score -1):

that's also happen to me, maybe you can try to press F9 after you restart your computer. then there's a  different drives will pop up then choose what you want.